# How to count time elapsed between two items in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like this:

```
events: 
 [{
   eventInfo: "START_event1",
   timeStamp: "2020-11-29T22:01:53.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
   eventInfo: "END_event1",
   timeStamp: "2020-11-29T22:04:00.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
   eventInfo: "START_event1",
   timeStamp: "2020-11-29T23:00:00.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
   eventInfo: "START_event2",
   timeStamp: "2020-11-29T23:01:53.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
   eventInfo: "END_event1",
   timeStamp: "2020-11-29T23:04:50.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
   eventInfo: "END_event2",
   timeStamp: "2020-11-29T23:24:00.634041+00:00"
  }]
```

The array will have multiple occurrences of an event with a same name. I am supposed to calculate the total time elapsed with event1, event2 and so on.

The issue is that there is no other way of knowing which event starts and endings are a pair other than the eventInfo string having start or end in the name. For example the consequent START_event1 and END_event1 are supposed to be a pair and so is the START_event2 and END_event2 (even though there is another START_event1 in between of them).

The end result I'm looking for is a new array where there are total run times for each event name.

```
[{
event1: totalRuntime
},
{
event2: totalRuntime
},
{
eventN: totalRuntime
}]
```

Comment: What type is `eventInfo` and the likes of `START_event1`?  Are those constants or strings?

Comment: Your input data sample has syntax errors

Comment: eventInfo is a string. For example "START_make_coffee", "END_make_coffee".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start for parsing through your events array and pairing up each start/end time.

The trick is each "START_" time event is added as a member of an object table. When the corresponding "END_" time event is encountered, it pulls the original start time out of the table, computes the difference, and adds the running table to another table.

The return value from `parseEventsList` is an object (map) that has the total running time (in milliseconds) of each event. Converting that object into the format you need is an exercise left for you.

Example run:

```
> totals = parseEventsList(events)
{ event1: 417000, event2: 1327000 }
```

```js
function parseEventsList(events) {
   var startTimes = {};
   var totals = {};

   for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {

       let date = new Date(events[i].timeStamp);

       if (events[i].eventInfo.substr(0,6) == "START_") {
          let eventname = events[i].eventInfo.substr(6);
          startTimes[eventname] = date;
       } else if (events[i].eventInfo.substr(0,4) == "END_") {

          let eventname = events[i].eventInfo.substr(4);
          if (startTimes[eventname]) {
             if (totals[eventname] === undefined) {
                 totals[eventname] = 0;
             }
             totals[eventname] += (date - startTimes[eventname]); 
          } else {
             // error: end event with no matching start event
          }
       }
   }
   return totals;
}

let events =  [{
   eventInfo: "START_event1",
   timeStamp: "2020-11-29T22:01:53.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
   eventInfo: "END_event1",
   timeStamp: "2020-11-29T22:04:00.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
   eventInfo: "START_event1",
   timeStamp: "2020-11-29T23:00:00.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
   eventInfo: "START_event2",
   timeStamp: "2020-11-29T23:01:53.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
   eventInfo: "END_event1",
   timeStamp: "2020-11-29T23:04:50.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
   eventInfo: "END_event2",
   timeStamp: "2020-11-29T23:24:00.634041+00:00"
  }];
  
  let totals = parseEventsList(events);
  
  console.log(totals);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume all data is `string` in your example.

Duplicate events is ignored

```js
const events = [{
    eventInfo: "START_event1",
    timeStamp: "2020-11-29T22:01:53.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
    eventInfo: "END_event1",
    timeStamp: "2020-11-29T22:04:00.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
    eventInfo: "START_event1",
    timeStamp: "2020-11-29T23:00:00.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
    eventInfo: "START_event2",
    timeStamp: "2020-11-29T23:01:53.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
    eventInfo: "END_event1",
    timeStamp: "2020-11-29T23:04:50.634041+00:00"
  },
  {
    eventInfo: "END_event2",
    timeStamp: "2020-11-29T23:24:00.634041+00:00"
  }
]

s = []
final = []

events.map(x => {
  var eventId = x.eventInfo.match(/\d+/)
  if (!s.some(x => x.id == eventId[0] && (s.some(c => x.end != null)))) {
    if (x.eventInfo.includes("START")) {
      s.push({
        id: eventId[0],
        start: x.timeStamp,
        end: null
      })
    } else {
      if (s.some(x => x.id == eventId))
        s.find(x => x.id == eventId[0]).end = x.timeStamp
      else
        s.push({
          id: eventId[0],
          start: null,
          end: x.timeStamp
        })
    }
  }
})

s.map(x => {
  var time = (new Date(x.end).getTime()) - (new Date(x.start).getTime())
  final.push({
    ['event' + x.id]: time
  })
})
console.log(final)
```